# Can this python web-scraper run in dedicated server?

Tags: python, web

I run this web-scraper on my notebook - it uses Firefox (selenium - webdriver) to get the data - it must actually open the Firefox because the data are created by JavaScript. So I wonder if dedicated server can open Firefox and get the data too - I think dedicated servers have no display so it will not work? The script is much more complicated (well 152 lines) - I pasted only the parts which I think will not work. I believe importing the data into PostgreSQL is no problem in dedicated server.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import lxml
    import re
    import psycopg2
    import sys

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.set_window_position(-9999, -9999)
    driver.get("http://rodos.vsb.cz/Road.aspx?road=D2")

    time.sleep(20) #waits till the page loads

    html_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')
# finds tags with speed information (km/h)
for i in (soup.find_all("tspan", {"id" : re.compile("tspan_Label_\w*")})):
            if re.match("^[0-9]+$", (str(i.getText()))) is not None:
                if (str(i.parent.get('fill'))) == '#5f5f5f':
                    list1.append(i.getText())
```

Comment: Have you considered using PhantomJS instead of Firefox it is headless (it does not need a GUI)?

Comment: ^ while you _can_ run a graphics interface in a remote server, using a non-GUI browser as Klaus suggests may be much easier

Comment: I tried PhantomJS on my notebook but it did not create the JavaScript elements in that page. Maybe I did something wrong - are you sure PhantomJS can run the JavaScript and scrap the elements created by JS?

Comment: Also you can get the Ajax data directly. It contains am SVG with XML data that can be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is [pyvirtualdisplay](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay):

```
pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

pyvirtualdisplay will emulate the browser of your choice in memory without actually opening a browser.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

# Set screen resolution to 1366 x 768 like most 15" laptops
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 768))
display.start()

# now Firefox will run in a virtual display.
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

# Sets the width and height of the current window
browser.set_window_size(1366, 768)

# Open the URL
browser.get('http://rodos.vsb.cz/Road.aspx?road=D2')

# set timeouts
browser.set_script_timeout(30)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(30) # seconds

time.sleep(20) #waits till the page loads

    html_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')
# finds tags with speed information (km/h)
for i in (soup.find_all("tspan", {"id" : re.compile("tspan_Label_\w*")})):
            if re.match("^[0-9]+$", (str(i.getText()))) is not None:
                if (str(i.parent.get('fill'))) == '#5f5f5f':
                    list1.append(i.getText())
```